# Get nest object by ID in MongoDB document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to retrieve a comment in a post to edit. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Here's what my **Post** document looks like:

```
{
    "title" : "First Node.js App",
    "body" : "testing 123",
    "status" : "public",
    "user" : "John Doe",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-12-21T18:30:09.779Z"),
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "commentBody" : "This is awesome! ",
            "commentUser" : ObjectId("5a3bfd5a9e65351f9c18ba18"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a3c02379e65351f9c18ba1a"),
            "commentDate" : ISODate("2017-12-21T18:49:27.620Z")
        },
        {
            "commentBody" : "This is second comment.",
            "commentUser" : ObjectId("5a3bfd5a9e65351f9c18gt19"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a3c02379e65351f9c18ba1b"),
            "commentDate" : ISODate("2017-12-21T18:49:27.620Z")
        }
    ],
    "allowComments" : true
}
```

How do I retrieve comment id ObjectId("5a3c02379e65351f9c18ba1a")?

I've tried the following but had no luck:

```
const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
const comment =  post.comments.find({"_id": req.params.commentid});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callback to [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const comment = post.comments.find((el) => el._id === req.params.commentid);
```

Comment: Hi Kristianmitk, thanks for your suggestion. unfortunately I'm getting "undefined" on consle.log(comment ).

Comment: I found out the issue, changing the "el._id === req.params.commentid" to "el._id == req.params.commentid" worked. thank again for your help!